# My Arduino Nano clone doesn't show in the serial this simple code. Why?

Tags: arduino-nano

Here is the code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.print("hi");
}
void loop() {
}
```

The product is in [here](http://hobbycomponents.com/featured/98-arduino-compatible-nano-v30-with-free-usb-cable).

I also installed the drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't "started" the serial interface.  Before you use the serial you need to tell it to initialize the hardware and how fast you want to communicate.

You need to add, for instance,

```
Serial.begin(9600);
```

to your `setup()` function before you do your `Serial.print()`.

Comment: What does the command do exactly? Why 9600?

Comment: Still can't see nothing in the serial

Comment: It makes it work. At the moment you have sat in your car and and are pressing the accelerator - but you forgot to start the engine. You need to make sure that you are communicating at the same speed as you have specified in the begin() function call. Also you may see more if you change your `print` to a `println` and place it in loop instead of setup so it sends it over and over again.

Comment: still nothing in the serial monitor

Comment: Are you sure you are programming the board? Try using the Blink example to make sure you are actually programming it. Then try the AnalogInOutSerial example.

Comment: Even the blink example doesn't work in fact, because it doesn't change the blinking on the board.
Here's the proof I'm programming it?
Sketch uses 1,788 bytes (5%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30,720 bytes.
Global variables use 204 bytes (9%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1,844 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.

Comment: Houston, same message if I disconnect the board. Now what?

Comment: Ohhh I made the verify before the Upload. Now it works